# How to map Cmd + Shift + ] to switch tabs in vim

Tags: vim

Is it possible to map "Cmd + Shift + ]" to switch tabs in vim? If so, what should I add to my .vimrc file?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't use a Mac, but I believe that you cannot chain <kbd>⌘</kbd> and <kbd>Shift</kbd>. Might I suggest <kbd>Alt</kbd>? And since <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>]</kbd> is just `}`, give this a try:

```
noremap <A-}> gt
```

or

```
noremap <A-}> :tabnext<CR>
```

Then you should be able to use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>]</kbd> to move through your tabs.

Comment: Thanks, I ended up adding 

 `nnoremap { gT` to move through the tabs

Comment: Oh nice, I actually didn't know there was a normal mode command for that. Thanks! I'll add it to the answer. Side note: `gT` is previous tab. `gt` is next tab.